# How to use .java extensions API with Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, bitcoin, coinbase-api

I'm working on a project for Java using `BitCoin`. I downloaded an API from [here](https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-java).

I expected to get a `.jar` file but the files I downloaded are `.java` files. How do I use this API in Eclipse?

Comment: just put those java files with your other java files present in your project

Comment: You can download all jar files form [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dtcrck6nopltdyn/coinbase-java.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to import the containing folder as a project in Eclipse...

*.java files contain actual java code that needs to be compiled

*.jar is the compiled version of the code

so when you import it in Eclipse, try to run it, and then once it's working export it to *.jar

Comment: Sir, my project still is not recognizing my API. Please help sir.. :(

Comment: try to open .java files with notepad... they should contain code